# Shift Doublebond in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I'm new to `chemfig` and LaTeX in general and have a rather simple question (at least I hope it is simple).

I'm trying to draw a molecule, the MWE looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setatomsep{1.5em}
\chemfig{*6(=-*5(-*6(-=-=-)=-N(--[::-60])-)=-=-)}
\end{document}
```

I would like to draw both double bonds next to the 5-ring either inside OR outside of the 5-ring.

How could I possibly achieve that? The double bond shift feature which is described in the manual of the `chemfig` package doesn't really help, because the length of the bond differs.

EDIT
[image: For better unterstanding I have added a picture, orange, or green solutions, both would make me equally happy.]

Comment: For both solutions I do not see more problem that just change in the formula some single bonds (`-` character) by  double bonds (`=` character)  and vice versa.

Comment: From my experience, this will only change the position of the doublebond within the molecule but not actually the "side" it appears at.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your problem. What problem there are exactly with use `*6(=-*5(-*6(-=-=-=)--N(--[::-60])-)=-=-)`, for instance, to have two   "externals" double bonds in the 5-ring  ?

Comment: Wow, thats actually what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setatomsep{1.5em}
\chemfig{*6(=-*5(-*6(-=-=-=)--N(--[::-60])-)=-=-)}\qquad
\chemfig{*6(=-*5(-*6(-=-=-)=-N(--[::-60])-=)-[,,,,draw=none]-=-)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I especially like the `[,,,,draw=none]` in the second example so that the twice defined edge is only drawn once.